# Gnuplot showing plot, but the file is always 0kb

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot data using gnuplot, and have the graphs saved to an image file. The problem is that the image files are always 0kb.

```
file = "energy_distribution_b.dat";

set title 'Energy Distribution';
set output "graphs/energy_distribution_b.jpeg";
set key top left;

plot file using 1:2 with lines pt 7
```

The graph pops up, but when I check the image file for the graph, the filesize is 0kb. I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: What terminal type are you using? besides, the semi colons at the end are not needed.

Comment: You must set the terminal to match your output file, otherwise the file will be created but nothing will be written to it.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows systems is important closed file by set output "" after plot command

```
file = "energy_distribution_b.dat"
set title 'Energy Distribution'
set key top left
set output "graphs/energy_distribution_b.jpeg"
plot file using 1:2 with lines pt 7
set output
```